# What method can be used to find key phrases in sentiment analysis?

Tags: self-study, natural-language, sentiment-analysis

I've just completed a fastai NLP processing sentiment analysis, that is, a binary classification problem using text data. It turned out very well, but I'm wondering if there is a way to find the key phrases that are associated with a positive outcome.

I don't think that it's possible in fastai, so I'm wondering if there is another package that is capable of doing this, either in R or Python. Note I'm not looking for a single word "word cloud", rather, small phrases.

Comment: Not particularly related to sentiment analysis, but you could see what keyword extraction methods yield in your scenario. These methods will tell you which words are particular to the document, and might help you figure out which sentence is the "most important" for each document